# How to select a very last <li> in unknownd multi level <ul>

Tags: css, css-selectors

is there a possibility to select just a single last `<li>` in each multi-level list?

```
<ul class="root">
    <li>no</li>            
    <li>no</li>            
    <li>yes</li>
</ul>

<ul class="root">
    <li>no</li>            
    <li>no</li>            
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>no</li>            
            <li>yes</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

​
Free playground on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dizzyn/KMY3U/

Comment: see here. http://jsfiddle.net/KMY3U/3/

Comment: @Dev you were faster :) upvote...

Comment: @Dev notice that the last element of the second list is an `<ul>`, all of which becomes red in this case. The OP only wants to highlight the nodes marked with `yes`. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/KMY3U/5/ Not a single rule, though.

Comment: @Tom no need to use 2 li ;) but good 1

Comment: No you can't if you don't have a few informations about your nested lists, like their exact depths. You can select `.root li:last-child li:last-child li:last-child` for "*depth 3 lists*" but that won't even work with lists of different depths. OT: beware that in this example you're using color to coney information. That won't be perceived by blind people, many partially-sighted people, etc (though you only want to "select" items, we don't know what you'll do with them next)

Comment: @FelipeAls agreed but didn't got this part : `That won't be perceived by blind people`

Comment: @Tom Here's an updated fiddle with valid code (yours has an `ul` direct child of `ul` though I think browsers fix this automagically), depths from 1 to 4 with also *"cousins"*. **[http://jsfiddle.net/KMY3U/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/KMY3U/6/)** The first cousin (the red "no") have NO way in CSS3 to know if he'll have a latter cousin or if he IS the last one in `.container`. Impossible task in CSS3 (just use JS or wait years for CSS4 parent selectors).

Comment: @Mr.Alien Blind people use screen readers that'll read out (or display on a Braille display) text and many informations but not color. So if you tell them to see the red text for error, they won't have a clue where this "red text" is ;) See WCAG2.0 Techniques [G14](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G14.html), [H92](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H92.html), [G182](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G182.html), [G111](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G111.html), [G138](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G138.html) for much more info about color use (but maybe OP want to style the last `li` differently)

Comment: @FelipeAls did knew that media attribute has a value for it but always used to wonder is that real imp ;)

Comment: Sorry to OP for hijacking his comments ^^ @Mr.Alien do you mean `media="braille"` instead of `"screen, projection"` for loading CSS files? Screen readers do use `screen`, never `braille` or anything else cause they run on top of OS, not even on the browser.

Comment: @FelipeAls: Your first comment is the right answer.

Comment: @FelipeAls: There is no parent selector in Selectors 4, and unless the spec allows using `!` more than once in a complex selector (e.g. with `:matches()`) it may very well not be possible even with Selectors 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, use `:last-child` CSS selector..

[**My fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TkTUq/3/)

CSS

```
ul li:last-child {
    color: #ff0000;
}​

li {
    color: #000000;
}​
```

You can also use this :

CSS

```
ul li:nth-last-child(1) {
   color: #ff0000;
}

li {
   color: #000000;
}​
```

`:last-child` selector selects every element that is the last child of its parent.

Note : This was a CSS3 implementation, so some browser's will ignore this but wont spoil anything cuz you are just changing the color..

Comment: Your fiddle shows that it's impossible with this single rule (a "no" item is colored in red).

Comment: @FelipeAls fixed :) and btw thanks for drawing my attention to it

Comment: I've updated the HTML code: http://jsfiddle.net/KMY3U/6/ with *cousins*. Won't work in CSS3 ;)

Comment: This was already demonstrated as not working in the fiddle given in the question. You can see the last `no` being colored red as well. `:nth-last-child(1)` is identical to `:last-child`.